# React redux Too many re-renders.React limits the number of renders to prevent an infinite loop

Tags: reactjs, redux

How do I fix this error.

Here is my code. first I use useSelector to call my reducer
and useEffect

```
const dispatch = useDispatch();
const calendarSelector = useSelector(state => state.calendarReducer);
const [stateEvents, setStateEvents] = useState(events);

useEffect(() => {
 dispatch(collection());

 if (!calendarSelector.loading) {
  const collection = calendarSelector.collection.events;
  console.log('events 123 ->', collection);
  setStateEvents(collection);
 }
}, [calendarSelector.loading]);
```

then on my calendarSelector.loading is false until he get data from api

```
//if (!calendarSelector.loading) { 
// const collection = calendarSelector.collection.events;
// console.log('events ->', collection);
// setStateEvents(collection);
//}
```

im getting my error on setStateEvents but if i use setTimeout like this

```
setTimeout(() => setStateEvents(events));
```

it fixes the error but the if (!calendarSelector.loading) {} keep running

[image of my console log](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VElw7.png)

Comment: Where do you use `if (!calendarSelector.loading) { ` and what is events?

Comment: What do you want to do it the calendarSelector.loading is false. Why setState there because that is the cause of your problem

Comment: default value of loading is true Im waiting for calendarSelector.loading to set false. it happen when dispatch(collection()) done getting data from api. so that calendarSelector.collection.events wll get a value before i use setStateEvents

Comment: Added an answer with the explanantion and possible solution

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is that you are trying to update state directly inside render which cause your component to go into an infinite loop once the loading state is false. You must instead use `useEffect` to update state when loading flag changes

```
useEffect(() => {
 dispatch(collection());
}, [dispatch]);

useEffect(() => {

    if (!calendarSelector.loading) { 
     const collection = calendarSelector.collection.events;
     console.log('events ->', collection);
     setStateEvents(collection);
    }

}, [calendarSelector.loading]);
```

however while the above will solve your issue, you must not copy props to state unless y0ou want to update the local state intermediately

You can directly use `calendarSelector.collection.events` in your component

Comment: still ddnt fix the error. BTW my dispatch(collection()); is also inside useEffect and im using hooks not components.

Comment: I agree, and I understand you are using hooks, which is why I suggested useEffect

Comment: BTW Too many re-renders. React limits the number of renders to prevent an infinite loop is Fixed with your solution. but it still calling calendarSelector.loading everysecond with infinit loop. like shown on my screenshot in my question

Comment: @pedopedo I hope you don't write `if (!calendarSelector.loading) { 
     const collection = calendarSelector.collection.events;
     console.log('events ->', collection);
     setStateEvents(collection);
    }` directly in render at all. If you still face the issue please show more code of the component

Comment: Exactly what you didn't want. You need two separate useEffects and not one

Comment: Damn soon. you God! Big thanks to you good bless.now it works perfectly after seperating useEffect().